# Relation Between Determinant and Eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Well,

If $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ and also $\lambda\neq 0$, how can you conclude that $\det(A)\neq 0$

Since $\det$ is not a linear operator, I do not see it as an immediate result, but may be I am missing something silly.

**EDIT** I mean all eigenvalues are nonzero, not just one.

Comment: $\det(A) = 0$ really means $0$ is an eigenvalue: $\det(A) = \det(A-0 \cdot I)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't conclud it. 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$  is a counter exampel (with $\lambda=1$)
If $0$ is not an eigenvalue you know that $\det(A - 0 I)\neq 0$ (when it is $0$ it is an eigenvalue).
$$\det(A-0 I) = \det(A) \neq 0$$

Comment: what is Joseph refering to [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26170/matrix-inverses-and-eigenvalues)

Comment: we know 0 is not an eigenvalue, so $\det(A - 0 I ) \neq 0$ so $\det(A)\neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$ be all distinct eigen values correspond to $A\in M_{n\times n}$ then $\ d etA=\lambda_1\lambda_2,...\lambda_n$ or if $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ be characteristics polynomial then $\ detA=a_0(-1)^n$